# python3 urllib import error

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I have searched some web,but did not fit to my situation. it's running fine on jupyter notebook and shell,but not on pycharm 2017.1.3.the version is Python 3.6.0 :: Anaconda 4.3.1 (64-bit)

```
from urllib import request

with request.urlopen('https://api.douban.com/v2/book/2129650') as f:
    data = f.read()
    print('Status:', f.status, f.reason)
    for k, v in f.getheaders():
        print('%s: %s' % (k, v))
    print('Data:', data.decode('utf-8'))
```

stack trace for the error

```
"D:\Program Files (x86)\Anaconda3\python.exe" D:/pyProject/liao/usual/urllib.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/pyProject/liao/usual/urllib.py", line 8, in <module>
    from urllib import request
  File "D:\pyProject\liao\usual\urllib.py", line 8, in <module>
    from urllib import request
ImportError: cannot import name 'request'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Is it possible you used Python 2.7 on the other system? The `urrlib` package changed ... see top of https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/urllib.html

Comment: @simonz no,I only get original python 3.6.1 and anaconda3 python 3.6.0,and pycharm interpreter is using anaconda3 python

Comment: @simonz are you sure what you mention is right information for this problem?

Comment: You have named your own program urllib.py - your import is finding that before the actual `urllib` module!

Comment: @jasonharper my mistake..this does make sense..please answer it and will be accepted

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem. Please rename your file to something else as the import is finding your file name `urllib.py` before finding the `urllib` package.